# Is there a way to disable "call from" when I use Google Voice?

Tags: google-voice

I love Google Voice, but I don't want people calling me to be asked to say their name and I don't want to be told to "press one" to accept their calls. I just want to get my calls. Is there a way to disable that feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to [voice.google.com](https://www.google.com/voice?pli=1#callsettings). Top right, click on Settings -> Voice Settings.  Go to "Calls" tab.  Turn Call Screening to "Off"